# Are period domains ever contractible

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, shimura-varieties, ag.algebraic-geometry, tag-removed, arithmetic-geometry

Which simply-connected period domains are contractible?

Examples. Siegel upper-half space? Poincare upper-half plane? Universal cover of a Shimura variety?

Are these contractible?

Comment: "half-space", "half-plane": what do you think?

Comment: @Jason S: I am also a Jason S!

Comment: I would like to know the answer for the universal cover of a Shimura variety. But maybe this would be more obvious if one could remember the definition of Shimura variety off the top of one's head.

Comment: dhagbert: see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/67699/ ...

Answer (score 3):

The universal cover of a Shimura variety is a bounded symmetric domain (that's part of the definition), and these are listed in the Wikipedia (under Hermitian symmetric spaces), so you can check this for yourself.